# Linq to SQL - Left Outer Join multiple conditions and show all columns

Tags: sql, linq, c#-4.0

I have perused the other questions regarding linking tables in LINQ with left joins using multiple conditions and tried what I thought were the relevant examples but I can't create the C# LINQ code to get the results I need.

I have two tables. The first is ProductionOptions and the second is ProductionOrderDetailsOptions.

This is the contents of the ProductionOptions table (filtered by optionType for brevity)

```
optionType  optionValue            order     showTextBox
----------------------------------------------------------
PACKAGING   BLACK BOX                   8   False
PACKAGING   CUSTOM FOLDING WITH LOGO    4   True
PACKAGING   FLANNEL DUST BAG            6   False
PACKAGING   FOLDING                     2   False
PACKAGING   IMAGE FOLDING               1   False
PACKAGING   NAVY BOX                    9   False
PACKAGING   OTHER                      13   True
PACKAGING   PLAIN FOLDING               3   False
PACKAGING   POLYBAG                     5   False
PACKAGING   SET UP BOX BLACK           11   True
PACKAGING   SET UP BOX CREAM           10   True
PACKAGING   SET UP BOX NAVY            12   True
PACKAGING   SHRINK WRAP                 7   False
```

This is the ProductionOrderDetailsOptions table:

```
orderNo detailKey   optionType  optionValue                 optionAdditionalInfo
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
000001  1           PACKAGING   IMAGE FOLDING   
000001  1           PACKAGING   POLYBAG NULL
000001  1           PACKAGING   SET UP BOX BLACK            needs white lettering
000007  4           PACKAGING   CUSTOM FOLDING WITH LOGO    BMW
```

Now, what I would like is to show all rows in the ProductionOptions table when left-joined to the ProductionOrderDetailsOptions table.

Here is the SQL equivalent of the LINQ I need:

> SELECT *
>       FROM ProductionOptions po
>   LEFT JOIN
>   ProductionOrderDetailsOptions o on po.optionType = o.optionType
>       AND po.optionValue = o.optionValue
>       AND o.orderNo = '000001'
>   AND o.detailKey = 1
>   WHERE po.optionType = 'PACKAGING'

Here are the results I would like:
[image: Desired Output]

Ostensibly I want to bind the LINQ results to an object like a GridView.

If you got this far I would like to thank you for your patience...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this if you have a FK relation:

```
var items = ProductionOptions
.Where(p => p.ProductionOrderDetailsOptions == null || p.ProductionOrderDetailsOptions.optionType.Equals(p.optionType))
.Where(p => p.ProductionOrderDetailsOptions == null ||p.ProductionOrderDetailsOptions.optionValue.Equals(p.optionValue))
.Where(p => p.ProductionOrderDetailsOptions == null ||p.ProductionOrderDetailsOptions.orderNo.Equals("000001"))
.Where(p => p.ProductionOrderDetailsOptions == null ||p.ProductionOrderDetailsOptions.detailKey.Equals(1))
.Where(p => p.optionType.Equals("PACKAGING"))
.AsEnumerable();

foreach(var item in result)
{
   //ProductionOptions
   Console.WriteLine(item.optionType);
   //ProductionOrderDetailsOptions
   Console.WriteLine(item.ProductionOrderDetailsOptions.detailKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Left outer join between two tables can be done like this. Here the thing to notice is that in select statement g can be null so while fetching the field value from left outer join, we have to handle null condition..

```
(from po in ProductionOptions.Where(p=> p.optionType == "PACKAGING")
 join o in ProductionOrderDetailsOptions.Where(d=> d.orderNo == "000001" && d.detailKey == 1 )
 on new {po.optionType, po.optionValue } equals new {d.optionType, d.optionValue } into gs
 from g in gs.DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new {po.optionType, ..
             orderNo = g?.orderNo, ...}
 )
```